# Update UI control in Task

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await, task

Does it right code, if I update my UI controls in task like this?
Or it's wrong, and I need use smth like Control.Invoke?

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = await Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Foo();
        return "Completed";
    });
}

private void Foo()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: you likely should invoke.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The BCL addresses this specific scenario with the [IProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, implemented in the [Progress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) class, to provide rich asynchronous progress reporting. This is available in .NET 4.5, or .NET 4 with the [BCL Portability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/bcl.aspx) Nuget package. A lot of BCL classes accept an IProgress parameter for progress reporting.

Servy's answer addresses the immediate problem of how to update the UI after an asynchronous operation, but that forces you to mix UI code inside the long running operation. `IProgress` allows you to make an [OnReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159267(v=vs.110).aspx) call with your report data without any concerns about marshalling the call to the proper thread, synchronization contexts, UI specific calls etc.

Your code can be as simple as this:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var progress=new Progress<string>(msg=>textBox1.Text = msg);
    await Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => Foo(progress));
}

private void Foo(IProgress<string> progress)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        progress.OnReport(i.ToString());
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    progress.OnReport("Finished");
}
```

Or you can use a more complex progress type, eg

```
class MyProgressData
{
    public string Message{get;set;}
    public int Iteration {get;set;}
    public MyProgressData(string message,int iteration) ...
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var progress=new Progress<MyProgressData>(msg=>{
        textBox1.Text = msg.Message;
        textBox2.Text=msg.Iteration.ToString();
    });
    await Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => Foo(progress));
}

private void Foo(IProgress<MyProgressData> progress)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        progress.OnReport(new MyProgressData("Hi",i));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    progress.OnReport("Finished");
}
```

The beauty of this is that you can completely decouple processing from reporting. You can put the processing code in a completely different class or even project from your UI.

Answer (score 4):

You can just run the code to see that it won't work, and that your program will crash, as you are touching the UI from a non-UI thread.

You should instead update the UI *as a continuation to the task* that is scheduled to run in the UI thread.  `await` does all of this for you, making the code pretty trivial.

You also shouldn't create a thread pool thread just to have it sit there and do nothing while you sleep for a fixed amount of time.  Use `Task.Delay` instead.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    textBox1.Text = "Completed";
}
```

Comment: A better solution would be to use [Progress<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160061(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid mixing processing and UI code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Assuming `Delay` here is representitive of some non-UI work then you *wouldn't* be mixing UI and non-UI code, as it so happens that the progress updates can be made entirely outside of the scope of the non-UI code.  If that wouldn't come out so nicely then yes, that can be a useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Foo` method will throw, since you're trying to update a UI control from a background thread.
If `Foo` did something arbitrary, which doesn't evolve any UI controls, then your `textBox1.Text = await Task.Factory.StartNew` would be fine, since you use `await` and the `SynchronizationContext` would be implicitly captured and used once the `await` completes, which would make the assignment on the UI thread.

This doesn't make too much sense, but if you wanted to update a control from inside the `Task`, you'd have to use `Control.Invoke`.